# How do I ensure my function isn't called until after a certain point in my Gulp stream?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm trying to write a Gulp task that will bump my project version and commit the changes to the relevant files, but only if the version has not already been bumped.

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
/**
 * Plugins being loaded are:
 * gulp-bump
 * gulp-git
 * gulp-if
 */

// Wrapping module.exports = function... omitted

function getVersionFromFile() {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json')).version;
}

// This task is run as part of the build process
gulp.task('bump-version-if-needed', function(done) {
    // Only bump the version if the current version is the same
    // as the most recent git tag
    $.git.exec({args: 'describe --abbrev=0'}, function(err, stdout) {
        var lastTag = stdout.match(/v(\d*\.\d*\.\d*)/)[1],
            currentVersion = getVersionFromFile();

        gulp.src(['./package.json', './bower.json'])
            .pipe($.if(lastTag === currentVersion, $.bump()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
            .pipe($.if(lastTag === currentVersion, $.git.add()))
            .pipe($.if(lastTag === currentVersion,
                $.git.commit('Version is now ' + getVersionFromFile())))
            .on('end', done);
    });
});
```

This nearly works, except that the second call to `getVersionFromFile()` to get the version number for the commit message is returning the old, un-bumped version, as it is called before the stream is executed. I can't pass a callback to `$.bump()` to retrieve the new version, it only takes an options object.

I had previously split the git add and git commit part of this task off into their own task - `getVersionFromFile()` then returned the correct value, but I lost the ability to conditionally run the git commands and an error would be thrown if there were no changes to commit (which would happen when the version hadn't been changed by `bump-version-if-needed`).

Is there a way to change how I'm calling `getVersionFromFile()` so that it's only run after Gulp has written the changes to my file?